# Regex, replace all occurrences of subgroup

Tags: c++, regex, replace

I want to replace "all" occurrences of "a" within the parenthesis with "b".

I have:

```
std::string s = "a(aaa)a";
std::regex e("(\\(.*?)(a)(.*\\))");
s = std::regex_replace(s, e, "$1b$3");

std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

It outputs:

```
a(baa)a
```

But I want:

```
a(bbb)a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only proper solution is to do two regex searches. One to extract the parenthesis substring and then to perform a second regex on that string.

```
std::string in = "a(a a)a( a ) a";
std::regex re("\\(.*?\\)");
std::smatch m;
std::string out;
while (std::regex_search(in, m, re))
{
    out += m.prefix();
    std::regex re("a");
    out += std::regex_replace(m[0].str(), re, "b");
    in = m.suffix();
}
out += in;

std::cout << out << std::endl;
```

Input:

```
a(a a)a( a ) a"
```

Output:

```
a(b b)a( b ) a
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code is generalized. Supports **PCRE**, **PCRE2** and **stl** regex libs

```
bool U::String::replaceExAll(string &s, const string& replace_this_reg_ex, const string& replace_with, bool case_sensitive, bool extended)
{
#ifdef UTIL_USE_PCRE
    pcrecpp::RE_Options options;
    options.set_utf8(true);
    options.set_caseless(!case_sensitive);
    pcrecpp::RE(replace_this_reg_ex, options).GlobalReplace(replace_with, &s);
    return true;
#elif UTIL_USE_PCRE2
    jp8::Regex re(replace_this_reg_ex);
    if(!case_sensitive)
            re.addPcre2Option(PCRE2_CASELESS).compile();

    jp8::RegexReplace& rp = re.initReplace();
    rp.setSubject(s)
                .setReplaceWith(replace_with)
                .setBufferSize(s.length() * 2);

    if(extended)
        rp.addPcre2Option(PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED);
    rp.addPcre2Option(PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL);
    // PCRE2_DOTALL PCRE2_MULTILINE PCRE2_UTF does not work

    s = rp.replace();
    return re.getErrorNumber() == 0;
#else
    regex rx = regex(replace_this_reg_ex, case_sensitive ? 0 : regex_constants::icase);;
    std:string temp = std::regex_replace(s, rx, replace_with);
    s = temp;

    return true;
#endif
}
```

for c++ PCRE2 wrapper use this lib: [JPCRE2](https://github.com/jpcre2/jpcre2)

Comment: Please format your code and don't use new/delete. Thank you.

Comment: `PCRE2_DOTALL PCRE2_MULTILINE PCRE2_UTF does not work` It won't work if you add it to RegexReplace object. These are compile options. The regex needs to be compiled with these options.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the job:

```
const std::string in = "a(aaa)a";
const std::regex re("(\\(.*?)(a)(.*\\))");

std::string out = in;
while (std::regex_search(out, re)) {
    out = std::regex_replace(out, re, "$1b$3");
}

std::cout << in << std::endl;
std::cout << out << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
a(aaa)a
a(bbb)a
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this directly with `std::regex_replace`; it doesn't seem to be covered in either of the relevant regex format specs. However, you could simply do something like this:

```
std::string s = "a(aaa)a";
std::regex re("(.*\\()(a*)(\\).*)"); // Regex amended to capture all a's between ()
std::smatch m;

std::regex_search(s, m, re);
s = m.format("$1" + std::string(m[2].length(), 'b') + "$3"); // match length known here
```

Since all you really needed to know in addition to the match was how many b's you had to put in there.

Comment: Smart, but it's not quite what I had in mind. It covers my example I have to admit, but I need a solution where the subgroup can occur anywhere within the parenthesis.